# Does Ruby have something like JavaDoc?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I am trying to learn Ruby, but I am having problems using the API. 
For example, I am looking at this:

**decode(json)
Converts a JSON string into a Ruby object.**

```
# File lib/active_support/json/decoding.rb, line 11
11:       def decode(json)
12:         YAML.load(convert_json_to_yaml(json))
13:       rescue ArgumentError => e
14:         raise ParseError, "Invalid JSON string"
15:       end
```

How can I find out about how to use the returned "Ruby Object"? Like the methods available and etc? Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it has:

http://ruby-doc.org/

Look for example:

http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/

There you could search api by name of method or name of the class.

Comment: Thanks, seems like the quality of documentation is really not consistent, I was looking at a gem and it had no documentation at all, that's why I was confused, but the ruby core stuff is really well documented, thanks for the answers

Comment: You are right, Ruby is well documented but Rails not so good. I didn't looked for method you are looking for, I thought it's just example of Ruby method. This method `decode` is from Rails framework so you could look for http://api.rubyonrails.org/, but it's not so good like Ruby one.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

http://ruby-doc.org/

and this

http://rubyonrails.org/documentation